# TypeError: query.findAll is not a function node js mysql

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, mysql-connector

i am trying to pass the sql query parameters to data access js file. i have imported the function in current file, but still am getting the below error.

current file

```
const tcount = async (value) => {
  const sql = 'trainingcount';
  const result = await query.findAll(sql);
  return result;
}
```

data access file

```js
const query = (results) => {
  findAll: async (sql, result) => {
    connection.query(`SELECT * FROM trainingcount`, (err, rows) => {
      if (err) {
        return results(null, err);
      } else {
        return results(rows);
      }
    });
  };
};

export { query };
```

> (node:11132) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError:
> query.findAll is not a function

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what `query` is supposed to be. It looks like it's a function with a single parameter, but you're trying to access a property on it.

Comment: Please show us how you import the `query` object in the 'current file'

Comment: i have done the import using import {query} from '../helpers/dataManager.js';

Comment: How are you using `query`? Are you using it anywhere else? Did you write it, or did you find it somewhere? If you found it somewhere, maybe they have examples of how to use it? Because it looks like you're not using it the way it's supposed to be used.

Comment: i created the `query`. i am using only on dataManager file. i tried to change the name but still the same error exists

Comment: If you wrote it, then how do you intend to use it? Why did you write `query = (results) => { ... }` and not `query = { findAll: ... }`? What is `results` for? Also, `query = (results) => ...` is the same as `query = function(results) { ... }`, so `query` is a function, it's not an object with a `findlAll` property as you expect.

Comment: My mistake. i corrected and it is returning as expected. Thanks for the explanation

Comment: No problem. Take a look at @gbalduzzi's answer as well to see how to wrap that callback into a `Promise`.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Check @rid solutions on the comments for the specific problem of calling the proper function. My answer solves a different problem in OP code.

---

you call `return` inside the callback function, so you are returning THAT function, not `findAll`. You need to return a Promise:

```js
const query = (results) => {
 findAll: (sql, result) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   connection.query(`SELECT * FROM trainingcount`, (err, rows) => {
    if (err) {
     reject(err);
    } else {
     resolve(rows);
    }
   });
  });
 };
};

export { query };
```

Comment: Thank you explaining on how to return  @gbalduzzi .learned a good way to code